# python strptime wrong format with 12-hour hour

Tags: python, strptime

My string format currently is `datetime.strptime(date_as_string, '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p')`

this unfortunately does not work with input such as **1/12/07 00:07 AM**

How I can get strptime to recogize this format ?

EDIT:

> ValueError: time data '1/12/07 00:07 AM' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p'

Comment: %I should recognize the 0. Can you post more details such as an error message?

Comment: That's because '00' is not a valid *12-hour* hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'00' is not a valid 12-hour hour, but if your input date string is inconsistently formatted you might be able to get away with something like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> date_as_string = '1/12/07 00:07 AM'
>>> format_12 = '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p'
>>> format_24 = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M %p'
>>> date_string, time_string = date_as_string.split(' ', 1)
>>> try:
...     dt.strptime(date_string + ' ' + time_string, format_12)
... except ValueError:
...     dt.strptime(date_string + ' ' + time_string, format_24)
... 
datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 1, 0, 7)
```

Comment: You're right this one is working. My mistake is elsewhere, I edit my question

Comment: @zepatou I've edited my answer to match your updated question.

Comment: That's working, thanks ! Should I edit my question title to better reflect what my problem was ?

Comment: @zepatou If you think you can improve the findability of your question then by all means. :)

Answer (score 1):

`'1/12/07 00:07 AM'` has incorrect format because in the 12-hour format the hour can be in range 1-12 and not 0.